# React router v4 wildcard next to index route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

Let's say we have this setup

```
const Parent = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/data" component={Child}
  </Switch>
)

const Child = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={SomethingList} />
    <Route path="/:id" component={ShowSomething} />
  </Switch>
);
```

When I render parent, I would expect `someUrl/data` to render `SomethingList` and `someUrl/5` to render `ShowSomething`. What actually happens is that both render `ShowSomething`.

How do I get the behavior I'm expecting with react-router v4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `/:id` doesn't mean it has to be an integer value. It can be whatever like: `/some-path` - and `id` would equal to `some-path`. That's why you get this behavior.

In your context, the only way to render `SomethingList` is to use `/` route. Nothing else will match. I would do it like this:

```
const Parent = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/data" component={Child}
  </Switch>
)

const Child = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/data" component={SomethingList} />
    <Route path="/data/:id" component={ShowSomething} />
  </Switch>
);
```

I guess you think that you can declare relative paths in your child component, which (I think) is not possible with RR4.

Comment: Wouldn't this make `/data/data` be the required path for the list?

Comment: Nevermind. That seems to work. So react-router has some special rules for routes matching the parent?

Comment: No. Your paths have to be absolute. You think that children components inherit route from the parent component. Which cause you an error. Do you get it?

Comment: You need to use absolute URLs even if you are deep, deep in a component tree.

Comment: Oh wow. That means my stuff just happens to be working because I'm not using the `exact` property.